# Why is this echo command not working?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I want to overwrite `/etc/postfix/master.cf` with my own content. I'm using `echo "<content>" > /etc/postfix/master.cf` to try and accomplish this.

But when I do:

```
echo "#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: 'man 5 master').
#
# Do not forget to execute 'postfix reload' after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing 'lmtp' master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd='lmtpd -a' listen='localhost:lmtp' proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
# SpamAssasin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}" > /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

I get a lot of errors:

```
echo "#
> # Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
> # of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: 'man 5 master').
> #
> # Do not forget to execute 'postfix reload' after editing this file.
> #
> # ==========================================================================
> # service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
> #               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
> # ==========================================================================
> smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
> #smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
> #smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 configuration details.
> configuration details.
#
> #
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
> uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
>   flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
-bash: !rmail: event not found
> #
# Other external delivery methods.
> # Other external delivery methods.
#
> #
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
> ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop (>   flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop (=yes
ipient)
> pient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
> bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
>   flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
> scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
>   flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
> mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
>   flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
>   ${nexthop} ${user}
# SpamAssasin
> # SpamAssasin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
> spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
>         user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}" > /etc/postfix/master.cf>         /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}" > /etc/postfix/master.cf  1       oqmgr
root@<redacted>-1:~# tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
tlsmgr: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
No command 'rewrite' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rewriter' from package 'ladr4-apps' (universe)
rewrite: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
No command 'bounce' found, did you mean:
 Command 'kbounce' from package 'kbounce' (main)
 Command 'bounced' from package 'sympa' (universe)
 Command 'bouncy' from package 'bouncy' (universe)
bounce: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
No command 'defer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'refer' from package 'groff' (main)
defer: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
No command 'trace' found, did you mean:
 Command 'btrace' from package 'blktrace' (universe)
 Command 'itrace' from package 'irpas' (multiverse)
 Command 'ltrace' from package 'ltrace' (main)
 Command 'mtrace' from package 'libc-dev-bin' (main)
 Command 'tracer' from package 'pvm-dev' (universe)
 Command 'grace' from package 'grace' (universe)
 Command 'xtrace' from package 'xtrace' (universe)
 Command 'tracd' from package 'trac' (universe)
 Command 'strace' from package 'strace' (main)
 Command 'dtrace' from package 'systemtap-sdt-dev' (universe)
 Command 'rtrace' from package 'radiance' (universe)
trace: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
The program 'verify' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install argyll
root@<redacted>-1:~# flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
The program 'flush' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install flush
root@<redacted>-1:~# proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxymap: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
proxywrite: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
The program 'smtp' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install apcupsd
root@<redacted>-1:~# relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
No command 'relay' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rplay' from package 'rplay-client' (universe)
relay: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# #       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
root@<redacted>-1:~# showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
The program 'showq' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install showq
root@<redacted>-1:~# error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
No command 'error' found, did you mean:
 Command 'perror' from package 'mysql-server-5.5' (main)
error: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
No command 'retry' found, did you mean:
 Command 'retrv' from package 'atfs' (universe)
retry: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
discard: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
-bash: local: can only be used in a function
root@<redacted>-1:~# virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
No command 'virtual' found, did you mean:
 Command 'virtaal' from package 'virtaal' (universe)
virtual: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
No command 'lmtp' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lftp' from package 'lftp' (main)
 Command 'smtp' from package 'apcupsd' (universe)
 Command 'gmtp' from package 'gmtp' (universe)
 Command 'ldtp' from package 'ldtp' (universe)
 Command 'mtp' from package 'ferret-vis' (universe)
lmtp: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
anvil: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
No command 'scache' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ccache' from package 'ccache' (main)
scache: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
root@<redacted>-1:~# # pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
root@<redacted>-1:~# # agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
root@<redacted>-1:~# # and other message envelope options.
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
The program 'maildrop' can be found in the following packages:
 * courier-maildrop
 * maildrop
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
-d: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing 'lmtp' master.cf entry.
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Specify in cyrus.conf:
root@<redacted>-1:~# #   lmtp    cmd='lmtpd -a' listen='localhost:lmtp' proto=tcp4
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
root@<redacted>-1:~# #  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
root@<redacted>-1:~# #  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# #cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
root@<redacted>-1:~# #  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# #old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
root@<redacted>-1:~# #  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # ====================================================================
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
The program 'uucp' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install uucp
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
-bash: !rmail: event not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# # Other external delivery methods.
root@<redacted>-1:~# #
root@<redacted>-1:~# ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
ifmail: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@<redacted>-1:~# bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
The program 'bsmtp' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install bacula-common
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
-t: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
scalemail-backend: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
root@<redacted>-1:~# mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
mailman: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~#   flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
root@<redacted>-1:~#   ${nexthop} ${user}
No command 'list' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dist' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'lst' from package 'lustre-utils' (universe)
 Command 'slist' from package 'ncpfs' (universe)
 Command 'klist' from package 'heimdal-clients' (universe)
 Command 'klist' from package 'krb5-user' (universe)
 Command 'listg' from package 'nauty' (multiverse)
 Command 'hist' from package 'loki' (universe)
 Command 'flist' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'last' from package 'sysvinit-utils' (main)
 Command 'gist' from package 'yorick' (universe)
 Command 'bist' from package 'bist' (universe)
list: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~# # SpamAssasin
root@<redacted>-1:~# spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
The program 'spamassassin' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install spamassassin
root@<redacted>-1:~#         user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
-f: command not found
root@<redacted>-1:~#         /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}" > /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

What should I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using double-[quoted strings](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) you have to be very careful. If you want to avoid some special behaviour for example when using an exclamation mark, try using `cat`:

```
cat > /etc/postfix/master.cf <<EOF
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: 'man 5 master').
#
# Do not forget to execute 'postfix reload' after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing 'lmtp' master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd='lmtpd -a' listen='localhost:lmtp' proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
# SpamAssasin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the error:

```
-bash: !rmail: event not found
```

That's interactive history expansion at work. Turn it off with

```
set +H
```

and retry the command. Re-enable it with `set -H`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $VARNAME gets evaluated by bash inside double quotes.  You'll need to escape and $'s with a \ like so: `\$`

Normally, you could just wrap the whole thing in single quotes, but because those are embedded in what you'd like to echo, you'd have to escape those too.

So you can either escape the single-qutoes or the $'s.

Or, just open up vi and type `c]]` before pasting everything in there and then following up with <kbd>esc</kbd>`:wq`.